# subversion release management with TeamCity

Tags: svn, teamcity, release-management

We currently use Subversion for our release management, and tag all of our releases (both to QA and to our production servers).  However, we'd like to create a single Release directory reflecting our newest release instead.  This way we can have TeamCity always pull from the same folder for continuous builds.  Also, if someone has to make a quick bug fix to production, they won't accidentally make it to the wrong branch.

For example, below is our current structure with a 'release' folder added.  Would there be an easy way to move a tagged branch to 'release' each time, or even have 'release' be a link to the newest release_* version?

[image: Our subversion folder structure]

**Clarification**

Here's an example of how our build/release process currently works:

- Today, I release a version of our web app to QA after TeamCity successfully builds it.  When doing so, I branch/tag it
- Tomorrow onward, devs continue making updates in the trunk.  These will not be pushed to QA until the next QA release
- On Wednesday, our QA team notifies us that they've found a bug.  We make a bug fix on the QA branch, merge the change back to the trunk, and push the updated QA branch back to QA.  ISSUE #1:  TeamCity is no longer working for us since we're in a #'d QA branch
- On Friday, QA approves the release for production, so we publish and branch/tag
- On Monday, a client calls with an issue requiring a small change to production.  We make the change in the release branch and merge back to the trunk.  ISSUE #2:  Once again, we're making a change without TeamCity helping us

Comment: +1 This has turned into an excellent question. I'm not sure our system copes with the issues listed and we're going to be in the exact same position described in september

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would (and do) take a slightly different approach to this. Source control management is primarily for, well, managing source and treating it as a means of tracking or implying releases can make life a little tricky. This is really the purpose of your continuous integration environment and it does a far better job of it than what SVN does.

I use TeamCity as the means of identifying both path and revision number to pull from SVN. It's easy enough to define this at build runtime and any release to production is always done with caution (i.e. carefully check both path and revision). In the absolute worst case, if you do screw it up, you can always re-run the build with revised parameters.

You really don't want to end up making code changes directly to a "Releases" folder - this is what the trunk is for if it's mainstream development or branches are for if you've had to adjust an earlier revision. It's sort of beating SVN into submission to do something that's not its core strength! On that front, you might find some of the tips in [The 10 commandments of good source control management](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/05/10-commandments-of-good-source-control.html) useful.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear about how you would use TeamCity for this.  Our web product has ~10 supporting EXE's, each of which are built and checked by TeamCity with each check-in.  However, once we start branching/tagging, how would I setup TeamCity to handle this unless the branches/tags were always named the same?  

Regarding your comment on making changes in the Releases folder, see my "Clarification" in the original question ... that describes our current build process.  

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Ignoring the type or number of units of code (ie 10 EXEs) and the purposes (QA or production), we're really just talking about the ability for TeamCity to pull code from a different path in SVN, right? That path will usually be a tag or a branch in your scenarios above so your question becomes "How can I pull from a different path under the same VCS root?". Have a look at "Example of configuration parameters usage" which walks through how to parametrise the checkout path: http://troy.hn/q3OQLu

Comment: the preferred approach would actually be a change to SVN so that a single tag always pointed to the newest release.  This way, any changes to release would automatically be checked by TeamCity (rather than needing to change TeamCity for each release).  I just have no idea how to do this.

Comment: This isn't really the purpose of a tag though Jess and you're still trying to instrument your build process from VCS which is why you're running into problems. I think you need to take one step back and look at the bigger objective you're trying to reach rather than trying to beat the technology into submission to achieve the conclusion you've already reached. Remember, a tag is just a "snapshot" of a project in time, not a working path to drive subsequent releases: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.tags.html

Comment: Troy - I understand .  I'm open to any suggestion that facilitates our build process, or open to any other build process that makes sense.  No matter what, we need to make changes to something in a release, whether by changing the actual tagged release or branching that tag.  Changes need to be separate from the dev trunk, then pushed back to the trunk as well (making changes to a release is common in any large project).  My goal was to allow TeamCity to verify that release changes were OK without reconfiguring TeamCity for every single release.  But you seem to suggest doing just that, right?

Comment: So parallel changes to the trunk obviously happen in branches and "pushing back" to the trunk is obviously a merge. The "problem" remains instructing TeamCity to pull from different paths in that as you say, it does mean some reconfiguration at each build. One mitigation would be to do the first QA release of each cycle from trunk and just specify the revision in the build params if it's earlier than the head then allow TeamCity to create the tag. *If* required, you then branch that tag (or trunk rev) and configure TeamCity to pull from there.

Comment: The other thing that strikes me - and maybe this is just agile principles on steroids - is that you appear to be doing a lot of branching & parallel dev. I wonder if there's something in your app lifecycle independent of VCS & CI that can be tweaked to avoid the frequent deployment of separate independent streams of development. Unless I'm missing something with the product capabilities, I can't see any other way of tackling this beyond the suggestions above. I hope one of these work out for you, feel free to email me if you want to take the discussion offline (link on http://troyhunt.com).

Comment: Thanks Troy - we're pretty early in our product cycle, so releases are occurring every few days.  I imagine this will all be easier once the product has been released for a while.  Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can easily script this so that after build completion you can copy a file or contents of a folder into release folder. You can even delete the contents of the release folder before doing this. So yes, since a branch or tag in svn is a copy operation you can do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

For each project we have a `Latest` folder that contains, well, the latest version (usually just the binaries).

This is extremely useful for continuous integration although we have to use custom MSBuild scripts to achieve this e.g do a Svn delete on the contents then an Svn copy to the Latest folder.

Comment: Hmmm ... what we are looking for is just the most recent Release, and the ability to update that release with any bug fixes (rather than making changes to the individually tagged releases).

Comment: @Jess seems I misunderstood your question. How often do you make your Releases? daily/weekly/manually? Also, what is in your Release folder - a copy of the trunk?

Comment: We don't use a release yet ... I was hoping to create a single folder to where we'd always branch a release.  That way TeamCity would always be building that folder, and if a developer needed to make a quick production bug fix, (s)he could do so in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `svn:external` property to have a folder called release point to a different tag. See [svn:external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html).

```
svn propset svn:externals 'release http://my_repo/tags/latest_tag' .
```

You would have to update the property value to point to the latest tag each time a new tag release was made.

Comment: Did you integrate that into your TeamCity build configurations? I do not see how this should work exactly. I think you will have to mark the verison to build on your own.

Comment: I haven't used it with TeamCity but I have used with the Hudson. My reading of question was about how you can link a statically named location in subversion to an actual changing version else where in the repository.

Comment: Okay. that's true if you execute the `svn` statement after the build automatically. This can also be done by TeamCity. I think that adding another build configuration, pointing to `release` should help to solve the problem